# Since + Past Simple

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Am I allowed to use since with the past simple? here are some examples.

> I forgot her since that day (since 1990)
>       It started raining since 3 o'clock
>       I didn't call him since childhood

It looks OK to me, but how about you?

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the three sentences as

> I forgot about her after that day in 1990
>
> It started raining at 3 o'clock
>
> I haven't called him since childhood

They are all rephrased but the last is the only one still using **since**, although the second sentence can be

> It has been raining since 3 o'clock

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67734/discussion-on-answer-by-weather-vane-since-past-simple).

Comment: Posts are flagged automatically by the system when the number of comments reaches a certain threshold. Moderators are expected to take action. Sometimes the comments are deleted, sometimes the comments are preserved in chat where the discussion can continue. This is not abuse of moderator privilege, this is fulfillment of moderator duties.

Comment: Whether you were referring to this exchange or the previous one, my response is the same: The moderation team follows the flags, and we clean up in a way that we believe is best for the site in the long run. Prolonged quibbling, snide remarks, and impolite comments are the least likely to survive. It often comes down to a judgment call, and it does get old being accused of "abusing" our "privilege" when we are just trying to keep things polite, friendly, edifying, and on-point. But all this has been [discussed before, on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2917).

Comment: @J.R. I do appreciate the hard work that the mods do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not allowed to do so.  It should read as follows:

> "I had/have forgotten about her since that day in 1990."
>
> "It has/had been raining since 3 o'clock." (never "started" and never
>   "has started")
>
> "I hadn't/haven't called him since childhood."

It has to be either present perfect or past perfect; it just depends on what you might be talking about.  For example:

> "I had forgotten about her since that day in 1990 until you just
>   reminded me of her."
>
> or
>
> "I have (completely) forgotten about her since that day in 1990. (i.e.
>   I have erased her from my mind; she is nothing to me; she is worthless
>   to me.)
>
> "It has been raining since 3 o'clock.  When will it stop?"
>
> or
>
> "It had been raining since 3 o'clock when it abruptly stopped and the
>   sun finally peaked out from behind the clouds."

Comment: (never "started" and never "has started") What do you mean by this? My book has a sentence like this: "It started raining an a hour ago" and can you consider this example too: "**Rose got many emails since she left the office**" or "**It was the band’s first live performance since May 1990**"

Comment: I don't think NC meant literally "never", but never in that particular sentence.  However, "It has started raining since 3 o'clock" is in fact grammatically correct.  ("It's raining now. Was it raining at 3 o'clock?" / "No, it wasn't. It's started raining since 3 o'clock.")  It's only "It started raining since 3 o'clock" that is impossible.

Comment: I don't believe "It started raining since 3 o'clock" could ever be grammatically correct.  "Rose got many emails since she left office" is wrong; it should be, "Rose has gotten many emails since she left office" or, if rjpond should be saying this, "Rose has got many emails since she left office." Brits like rjpond say "has got" herein.

Comment: I think some of the examples that you show us are informal, i.e. ungrammatical, but a lot of native speakers say things that are ungrammatical all of the time. It's just the truth. Many people are from different ethnic and regional backgrounds and have their own dialects, idiolects, etc.